# How to navigate a List tree which has List elements

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, tree

Basically, i need to iterate over each and every list there is in the many lists. The amount is not given, so i guess recursion must be used, but our assignment doesn't have recursion-like method, so i am at loss at the moment.
PS. The code is the same as my code, but i might've not translated it correctly, so just take note of the methods.

EDIT: What the program does - you can create states - then add sub-states to the states, and then sub-states to the sub-states etc.etc.

```
 class Tree
{
    public List<Branch> Branches;
    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (Branch item in Branches)
        {

        }
    }
class Branch
{
    public State state;
    public List<Branch> branch;
}
class State
{
    public string name;
    public string size;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably going to want to do is create some printRecursive(Branch branch) method, then iterate through that in the empty foreach you have in Print(). I'm assuming that a Branch with no sub branches just has an empty list. The method might look something like:

```
printRecursive(Branch branch) {
    printState(branch.state); 
    foreach(Branch b in branch.branch) {
        printRecursive(b); 
    }
}

printState(State state) {
    Console.WriteLine("State: " + state.name + ". Size: " + state.size); 
}
```

EDIT:

You don't even need these extra methods if you create a tree at each iteration. Seems like an impractical way to do it, but I don't see another option if you cannot make any new methods. Just make your Print() look like:

```
void Print() {
    foreach (Branch b in Branches) {
        // print b.state here 
        Tree tree = new Tree(); 
        tree.Branches = b.branch;
        tree.Print(); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: My programming lecturer said that we can't use any other methods than what we are given.

Comment: Oh I see, well now that you say that, you don't even need to create the other two methods. Just call Print() again inside Print(). Make sure you actually Print() the current branch before/after calling Print() again.